# information on Data Protection API (DPAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, hash, dpapi

I am currently writing a c# mvc web application in which password are being taken from a user and stored in a database - sql server. I need a way of hashing the passwords.

It has been recommended to be to use the Data Protection API (DPAPI). I am not familliar with it and from research on the internet, very little information exists on it.

Can anyone point in the direction for further information on it? OR give me an overview of how to set it up and work with it etc.

Answer (score 7):

The Data Protection API is primarily used for protecting cryptographic keys and secrets under a users credentials. If you want to store hashed passwords in a database, the DAPI isn't really what you want.

[The ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is used for managing users, including hashing passwords with a salt. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a method to just return a hashed password, so if you don't need the extra functionality, it might be worth extracting the relevant code from something like [CodeFirst Membership Provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/) (See Crypto.cs in the Source Code). The advantage here is this Membership Provider uses PBKDF2 to derive the hash, which is more resistant to brute force attacks given the number of rounds. It's also the method [StackOverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/#comment-59112) itself uses.

Answer (score 5):

.Net has a wrapper class for the DPAPI called [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx).  It it very easy to use, and contains just two static methods: `Protect` and `Unprotect`.  A How-to article can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229741%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The DPAPI does not require a key because it uses either the logged-in users's credentials or the machine's credentials to do the encryption, depending on what scope you choose when calling Protect.  Note that if you intend to store the encrypted data in a database, you must be sure to always use the same windows user account or machine (again, depending on the encryption scope), or else you will not be able to decrypt the data.  Thus, depending on your application, this API may not be optimal.  It is primarily intended for doing local encryption on a single machine rather than for distributed applications.