# Password Encryption using DPAPI and storing in Database

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, encryption

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a password using DPAPI and store it in Database . Does anybody have a sample code for the same? It would be appreciated.                    #Thanks in advance.

Comment: #code_required (trials)

Comment: Not sure that you need save it db, hope it`s answer,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149769/information-on-data-protection-api-dpapi